# Magento 2.0 Stable - Enabling Custom Module gives error

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.0, cli

**Download**

Today I downloaded the Magento 2.0 Full Release from the Magento website. I downloaded the *Full Release with Sample Data (ZIP with sample data)* and installed it. I wanted to test if my custom module build in RC-1 was still working however when I tried to enable the module I got an error.

**Module installation**

When I wanted to install my custom module I noticed the `app/code` directory disappeared and after a few clicks found that this was moved to the `vendor` directory. I assumed this was done by composer so decided to add my module to the `composer.json` in the document root. Running `composer update` installed the module to the vendor directory.

**Error**

Tried to enable module by executing the following command from my root directory:

`PHP -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Test_Module`

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/enable-module.html

Unfortunately, I get the following error; anyone has an idea what goes wrong?

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have fixed it by doing it without composer. I manually created a `code` directory within the `app` directory in the Magento root. Here I added the module in `/Vendorname/Modulename` which did the trick.

Not really the way I wanted to do it but for now It will have to do. If someone has a better answer and can tell me why what I did wrong for the composer way, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Giving full control (read/write/execute) to **var** and **pub** directory solved this issue for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Or, you may also try running the command using **sudo**.

```
sudo php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Test_Module
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were errors in the schema path in my `module.xml` file, and also some commented lines in `composer.json` that Magento 2 didn't like. Once I cleared those up, the modules registered.

For example, in `module.xml`, the path to the schema xsd was incorrect. Some people have the path as this:

`../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd`

(note the letter casing!)

where it should have been

`../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd`

There was also `schema_version="1.0.0"` in the `module` node that was deprecated(?), so I removed it.

Also, there is a "suggest" element in the `composer.json` object that I didn't need and had commented out with slashes, which caused an error.

Once I cleared those up, everything registered correctly.

Comment: I faced similar issue as I had schema_version in my module.xml file. To make it work i replaced it with setup_version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I followed several suggested stupid suggestions to fix the problem like delete my composer.json something like that.
But those didn't fix my problem.
Today, I faced the problem again and I tried a new approach to trace the problem.
All details and screenshot are in my personal blog post
http://david.firstbiz.cc/blog_detail.php?id=115
I described my steps here:

1. for CLI, please append "-vvv" and it will display function trace paths
2. try to load any product page and check your web server error log and you will be able to see more details.
3. the class name and the filename should be same (*this is the case I faced)